# How to submit html form data and pass it to another html page that consist of table without using php?

Tags: html

I created simple html page "output.html" that consist of table and one input button "add".

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width:70%;
    }
    td,th{
        border:1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align:left;
        padding: 8px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <center><h2>Employee Task Record</h2>
    <input type="button"  onclick="location.href='input.html';" value="Add" button class="button">
    <br><br>
        </body>
        <table>
        <tr>
    <th>Given Task</th>
    <th>Complete</th>
    <th>Task Type</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center> 
</body>
</html>
```

[image]
When I click add button,it opens html form "input.html".

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<center>
<form method="post" action="output.html">
Given Task : <input type="text" name="task"><br><br>
Complete: <input type="radio" name="taskDone" value="yes" checked> Yes 
<input type="radio" name="taskDone" value="no"> No<br> <br> 
Task Type: <select>
<option value="Meeting">Meeting</option>
<option value="coding">Coding</option>
<option value="documentation">Documentation</option>
</select> <br> <br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</center></div></body>
</html>
```

[image]

Now,when I submit form in input.html,I want to display the output in output.html where I created table.Sample output is given below.I want output in table in same format as shown below.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it without a server-side language, like PHP.
The nearest thing you can do is to do it in the same page (input and output) and adding rows with js (changing the DOM), but every time you will reload the page, you will lost all changes.